# CakePHP Date Validation using date array format

Tags: validation, cakephp

Greetings,

In my view I have a date input, set like so:

```
echo $form->input('cc_expdate', array('label' => __('exp. date', true),
        'type' => 'date', 'dateFormat' => 'MY', 'default' => date('Y'),
        'minYear' => date('Y'), 'maxYear' => date('Y', strtotime("+10 years")),
        'orderYear' => 'asc', 'separator' => '&nbsp;', 'monthNames' => false));
```

And in my model I have a validation rule, viz:

```
'cc_expdate' => array(
    'rule' => array('date', 'my'),
 'message' => 'Please select a valid expiration date'
)
```

But the validation always fails. When I look at `$this->data`, I see that the date is being passed through the form as an array (e.g. `'cc_expdate' => array('month' => '10', 'year' => '2010')`) but it seems the date validation rule expects a string like `10-2010`. I hunted around Cake and checked the documentation but could find nothing covering this. It seems this should be a simple task to handle, am I missing something simple or does Cake not have a built in validation for 'date' form elements?

cheers,
-Bri

Comment: The `Model` class has a [`deconstruct()` method](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#line-849) whose job is to put date arrays created by the `Form` helper back together again into a scalar value. In my experience, this "reconstruction" (IMO, the semantics of the method name are counterintuitive) happens _before_ the value is passed in for validation. I don't see anything that looks wrong in your snippet.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for pointing that out. I will take a look at the `Model` class to see if I can trace where the foobar is happening. For now I have added code to my controller that scalar-izes the date array into a new key (`$this->data['Model']['cc_expdate2']`) and added a custom validation rule to my model that verifies the value. (various aspects of Cake and its expected data formats prevent me from doing this only in the controller or model)

Comment: i posed a similar question a few weeks back. i'm surprised that date validation requires any extra code to perform. maybe they'll fine-tune this for cake 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution / hack is to add an extra hidden field representing the day. In this case, you'll send your form as Cake expects to be: array('day' => 1, 'month' => 12, 'year' => 1980) and now you have a normal date validation in your model and no problems of saving a corrupted  date value in your database.

Example:

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('YourModel.cc_expdate.day', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => 1));    
echo $this->Form->input('cc_expdate', array('label' => __('exp. date'),
            'type' => 'date', 'dateFormat' => 'MY', 'empty' => true,
            'minYear' => date('Y'), 'maxYear' => date('Y') + 10,
            'orderYear' => 'asc', 'separator' => '&nbsp;', 'monthNames' => false));
?>
```

Model:

```
'cc_expdate' => array(
            'date' => array(
                'rule' => array('date'),
                'message' => 'Invalid date',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a controller method recently where I was trying to save a month/year value into a MySQL date field and validation kept failing.  I was using my/MY in the model/view for the date settings and it was passing the year and month as expected to $this->data when I checked it in the controller.

What I did was to set the day key to "1" in the date array passed from the form before validation in the controller, and then validation worked.  This resulted in all my month/year dates being stored as the 1st of the month, which was fine for my app.

I'm still new to CakePHP, so this might be considered a hack, I'm not sure.  My date field in the database was a MySQL date field, so I was wondering if maybe it was failing validation for some reason due to the day being missing (maybe using varchar would save the month/year as a string?).

Comment: I tried this suggestion but still the validation would fail. I went ahead and stepped through the code in `validation.php` and `model.php` and found that date values start as an array and are converted into a mysql safe string in `model.php`. Of course, this format is YYYY-MM-DD, which fails when passed to the "my" validation rule. Changing the validation rule to "ymd" validates properly. This seems rather silly; it's like the date rule with anything other than "ymd" is for strings only, unless you convert your date arrays yourself or use a custom rule.

Comment: And thanks for the tip, it saves me from having to convert my db field to varchar.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Cake's month and year form fields, in order for the validation to work correctly, you must use the following notation:

Instead of .... 'column_name' for your rules, use 'column_name.month' and column_name.year.